# Datatables export not showing file save as dialog when click on excelHtml5 button

Tags: datatables

I am using Google Chrome and datatables.net using the example listed [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I am using the exact same java script library links and version of the plugin. However in the above example you get a dialog prompt to ask you to save the file when you click on the button.

In my project it is saving it directly to the User Downloads folder without prompting a File save as dialog. This happens for both the xlsx and csv

What causes my project that is the exact same as the example to not prompt me for a dialog but save directly to downloads folder?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prompted me for dialog when I deployed the site.

I realized the issue of no prompt only occurs when debugging in Visual Studio 2017.